# Project Euler 68: What is the maximum 16-digit string for a “magic” 5-gon ring? misunderstand the problem

Tags: algorithm

[((7, 5, 4), (10, 4, 2), (8, 2, 6), (7, 6, 3), (8, 3, 5)) This is the solution set from my algorithm which gave max sum string. Please some one can tell me what's wrong with this solution set. The numbers string of this solution set produce large number than the answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaD3Q.png)

[Question in the ProjectEuler](https://projecteuler.net/problem=68)

Comment: You shouldn't use external links. Try to type your algorithm and problem here.

Comment: For one you are using `7` and `8` twice in your solution, which is not allowed.

Comment: [Felipe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5039996/felipe), sorry for the external links. I'm new to stack overflow

Comment: [uneven-mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11941443/uneven-mark) Thanks for the reply. I found the mistakes with help of my friend. The solution set must contains all numbers from 1-10. In my solution set 1,9 are not included.

Comment: @CSA If you want a user to be notified that you commented, you need to write their name with an `@` in front, in the way I did at the beginning of this comment. Otherwise they will not get any notice about it.

Comment: @CSA Yes, that is equivalent to what I commented: Each number from 1 to 10 must be used exactly ones (as their are 10 nodes).

Comment: @uneven_mark Oh. sorry. I din't realize your answer. And also thank you for informing me how to notify. I din't knew it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found what's wrong here with help of a my friend. The solution set must contains all numbers from 1-10. In my solution set all numbers from 1-10 are not included.